Subscribing to Spl token missed transactions
As the title suggests I am subscribing to the logs of a token (e.g. 6ogzHhzdrQr9Pgv6hZ2MNze7UrzBMAFyBBWUYp1Fhitx) using websockets in Rust. The goal is to stream all transactions related to this token realtime. This on the surface looks like its working and I can receive transactions related to that token. Code below
        let program_id = Pubkey::from_str(program_id_str)?;
        let subscribe_message = json!({
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": self.next_id,
            "method": "logsSubscribe",
            "params": [
                {
                    "mentions": [program_id.to_string()]
                },
                {
                    "commitment": "confirmed"
                }
            ]
        });

The issue arises when particular transactions don't show up like this one for example. Is it due to the nature of the transaction or something related to the websocket or node provider? I am using the free Quicknode websocket endpoint for reference. I would appreciate if you could point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Since you're subscribing to the mint, 6ogzHhzdrQr9Pgv6hZ2MNze7UrzBMAFyBBWUYp1Fhitx, the websocket will only provide transactions that contain that account. SPL Token transfers don't require the mint to be present, as in instruction #4.2.
You might need to subscribe to additional programs that are known to not provide the mint account, like the raydium program.
